# Компиляция и запуск программ на графическом ядре процессора Broadcom (bcm2837)

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, компиляция, gpu, raspbian

У меня есть Raspberry pi 3 B+ с операционной системой Raspbian, установил на ней OpenCV. В пакете есть исходные коды (примеры), которые можно к примеру скомпилировать для запуска на GPU от Nvidia (в целях параллелизации) . Как скомпилировать? С какими флагами, чтобы запустить программу на графическом ядре bcm2837?